# Deleting/Reseting/Clearing a Bloom Filter in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, bloom-filter

I'm using a bloom filter in an app to scan for duplicates:

```
var BloomFilter = require('bloom-filter');

var numberOfElements = 30000;
var falsePositiveRate = 0.005;
var filter = BloomFilter.create(numberOfElements, falsePositiveRate);

var workFunction = function(var1, var2) {


        var bloomData = new Buffer(var1 + var2, "hex");

        if(!filter.contains(bloomData)){

          console.log("In the loop, adding the element to the bloom filter now!");
          filter.insert(bloomData);

         // work with the data and see if I found a needle in the haystack .. if yes, the bloom filter needs a reset !
        if (var === "123") {
          console.log("Needle found, resetting to fresh filter, new round !");
          var filter = BloomFilter.create(numberOfElements, falsePositiveRate);    // WRONG HERE  but you get the idea! 
        }


        } else {
          console.log("This entry is already in the bloom filter !");
        }
}



workFunction("1234", "1234");
```

After a certain amount of rounds I'd like to reset/clear/renew the filter as you see in my statement above but this of course fails because it is still in use at that point.

How would I write a callback or similar to get the filter resetted ?

Thanks

Comment: it should work if you remove the `var` before `var filter = ...` inside the callback, you are redefining a new locally scoped variable `filter`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that particular node modules doesn't have a `reset` method or anything similar in the API.

It seems like you can do 2 things at this point.

1.Make an issue for that repo asking for such a feature (or write your own Pull-Request) https://github.com/jasondavies/bloomfilter.js

2.Change the behavior of you `workFunction` to reset the filter.

```
var workFunction = function(var1, var2) {
  var filter = BloomFilter.create(numberOfElements, falsePositiveRate);
  // ...
}
```

Or something similar to reset iti yourself.

Comment: tried filter.clear() but it seems to destroy and not to actually clear the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter.clear()` ([implemented here](https://github.com/bitpay/bloom-filter/blob/master/lib/filter.js#L121-L123)).